# Get a specific line from a (line-break: normal) html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know if this is possible using JavaScript. I want to extract, say third line, from the following page:

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum felis elit, scelerisque id rhoncus et, hendrerit nec turpis. Phasellus eget condimentum justo. Aliquam porta, risus sed elementum hendrerit, turpis urna posuere libero, eget facilisis sem purus sed mi. Nulla pulvinar nibh quis bibendum lacinia. Aenean eu nibh pharetra, imperdiet mi eget, vehicula mauris. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus ante enim, bibendum quis turpis a, volutpat auctor mi. Mauris scelerisque sem a ornare dignissim. Nullam in sem ac turpis aliquet dictum sit amet dignissim est.</p>
```

I believe my html looks like:

[image]

> And the red underlined line is the third line, which is adjusted dynamically in the view.

I tried `.innerHTML` and `.innerText` method, but it fails to identify the line breaks.

I thought if I can somehow get the `scrollHeight` of each lines and then use JavaScript, but I didn't found any supporting methods on internet. Any ideas?

> **Note:** One can assume that he/she has access to the `p` element. We may proceed with a client-side JS/HTML solution.

Comment: Whats your end goal here?

Comment: @GetSet: I'm just trying to extract that line in a `string` variable.

Comment: You could `<span></span>` each word, then use a loop that determines when the Y coordinate changes, per word. As an idea anyway.

Comment: @GetSet: Okay, sounds good. But, I'm afraid if the text is too long.

Comment: The whole operation might tie up the ui thread, yes. Depending on the length of the text agreed. But as a concept it should be able to be "asynced" in some form or another.

Comment: @GetSet: your idea is helpful. You can add an answer.

Comment: Well, as a concept I am limited to only because I don't know how the `<p></p>` element is created? If it's server side, then it makes sense if the server did all the `<span></span>` business. However, for complete freedom, as in pure client side regardless of how `<p></p>` is generated, I could code it yes, but it would be likely deserve a more succinct implementation using jQuery. I could provide an algorithm however.

Comment: Suppose you went with a pure client side solution. (1) Use "inner-text" to save to a var. (2) Split the paragraph (the var) by "spaces" (to get the "words"). (3) Create a hidden `<p></p>` element with the same container dimensions and css styles of your real `<p></p>` element. (4) Write each word (separated by a space) from your `.split()` array to the hidden element but wrapped in a `<span></span>`. (5) Write the loop that checks on the Y of each word (each "span") in series. When the Y changes, you know you are on a "new line".

Comment: What do you mean by third line, the text after the second dot?

Comment: @SaymoinSam: forgive me, but i don't know where is second dot. I believe I'd made clear in the image where the third line is, by underlining it.

Comment: But you know that that line will not always be the third line, if there is some resizing

Comment: @SaymoinSam: Okay, now I understood your query. Well, I gave the picture just as an example to explain the problem clearly. I didn't meant to extract _"elementum...pulvinar"_ line, but the third line which was in front of you, in your window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do the following:

- Split the text of the paragraph by the `space` character to get all the words
- Set the paragraph's text to an empty string
- Append each word and measure the content size of the paragraph *(use this sparingly, measuring this way causes a lot of layout recalculation)*
- When the content size of the paragraph is not the same as the previous content size, we know that a line-break has happened
- When we are at the nth line, add the appended words until a new line is reached
- Said variable is the extracted string

This solution does not block UI events even when the text is very long. To achieve that in this solution, we can [split the long-running task to smaller ones](https://javascript.info/event-loop) so that UI events can still be handled. To split it, we can use `setTimeout(..., 0)`. Using `setTimeout` this way defers the shorter-running tasks. They only run if they are the most front of the [*message queue*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). Only when a shorter-running task is finished will the next shorter-running task be deferred to the end of the message queue. This allows for other UI-related messages (e.g. the callback function for your click event listener) to be run also; thus nonblocking.

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p')
const texts = p.innerText.split(' ')
const textsLength = texts.length
const nthLine = 3 // The line from which you extract the string

let i = 0
let currentWord = 0
let currentLine = 0
let currentBoxHeight = 0
let nthLineText = ''

p.innerText = ''
function getNthLineText() {
  // Split the long-running tasks of measuring words to only 100 word per callback function
  for (currentWord; currentWord < (i + 1) * 100 && currentWord < textsLength; currentWord++) {
    p.innerText += ` ${texts[currentWord]}`
    
    // Paragraph box is larger? Line-break occurred
    if (p.scrollHeight > currentBoxHeight) {
      currentBoxHeight = p.scrollHeight
      currentLine += 1
    }
    
    // We're at the nth line we want to extract, add the appended word to the result variable
    if (currentLine === nthLine) {
      nthLineText += ` ${texts[currentWord]}`
    }
  }
  
  if (currentLine > nthLine || currentWord >= textsLength) {
    console.log(`String extracted: ${nthLineText === '' ? 'None extracted' : nthLineText}`)
    p.innerText = texts.join(' ')
  } else {
    setTimeout(getNthLineText, 0)
  }
}

getNthLineText()
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum felis elit, scelerisque id rhoncus et, hendrerit nec turpis. Phasellus eget condimentum justo. Aliquam porta, risus sed elementum hendrerit, turpis urna posuere libero, eget facilisis sem purus sed mi. Nulla pulvinar nibh quis bibendum lacinia. Aenean eu nibh pharetra, imperdiet mi eget, vehicula mauris. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus ante enim, bibendum quis turpis a, volutpat auctor mi. Mauris scelerisque sem a ornare dignissim. Nullam in sem ac turpis aliquet dictum sit amet dignissim est.</p>
```

Comment: Brilliant solution